# RSpec testing concern with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a concern using Kaminari gem but don't sure how to test it. I have read about `share_examples` but it seem to not go through.

Here is my code

```
module LoadMoreConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  protected
  
  def load_more(objects)
    objects.present? ? !objects.last_page? : false
  end
```

spec/controllers/concern/load_more_concern_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.shared_examples 'LoadMoreConcern' do |klass|
  describe '#load_more' do
    let_it_be(:talk) { FactoryBot.create(:talk) }

    it "should return false if object is not present or is last page" do
      expect(subject.load_more(talk)).to be false
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller where I include this concern

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TalksController, type: :controller do
  it_behaves_like 'LoadMoreConcern'
end
```

And I'm getting this error when running spec

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/talks_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: it_behaves_like 'LoadMoreConcern'

ArgumentError:
  Could not find shared examples "LoadMoreConcern"
```

Anyone know which I should do or could point me to some resources? Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Shared examples are not autoloaded. Either add it to some place that is loaded for all examples by your `rails_helper` or require it explicitly where you need it.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec/controllers/concern/load_more_concern_spec.rb'

RSpec.describe TalksController, type: :controller do
  it_behaves_like 'LoadMoreConcern'
end
```